# How to include two or more Topics in the Same Page

Tags: doxygen, chm, html-help, doxygen-wizard, html-help-workshop

I am trying to make doxygen documentation using doxywizard and then fine tuning using HTML Help Workshop.
I wanted to create two Topics under the root and both pointing to different section in a same Page.
I can use add Topic and can add two listing under Root(section1 and section 2) but How can I link it with the two section in the same page of the document.
Basically creating two hyper link in the same page so the two topics can point to each separately.
[image]

I wanted to create Section1 and Section2 under Root just like Topic 1 and Topic 2.Where Section 1 and 2 should point to the same page's different section.

Or is there any Tool for the same?

Comment: Please note you can edit your *.hhc File and add a URL suffix as a anxhor by a text editor. Of course you need to insert the anchor in your HTML file and compile again.

Comment: The sample snapshots below show the added anchor syntax. BTW - the *.hhc file is the source for the Table of Contents (TOC, navigation pane of *.CHM). So, with some experience you can edit the URL and add the named anchor e.g. #SecondAnchor by your text Editor.

Answer (score 0):

There are many helpauthoring tools out there. Microsoft's HTMLHelp Workshop is nearly 20 years old stuff but free. E.g. search for FAR HTML as a low priced tool or many other ones.

If you really want to edit the CHM file generated by Doxygen of course you can do that. But this has a learning curve in help authoring and in using HTMLHelp Workshop.

In your Doxygen destination folder you'll find the HH files with extension *.hhp (project file).

You may know you can edit the *.hhp, *.hhk and *.hhc files by your preferred text editor like e.g. Notepad++.

As I understand you want to jump to section1 and section2 in the same file. I think you have to add a anchor tag in the HTML file. So you can specify the target URL including the anchor.

1. Open the *.hhp in HH Workshop
2. Select the Contents tab
3. Select a topic
4. Click the pencil icon "Edit selection"
5. Click the Edit button
6. Browse to your topic and select
7. NOTE: Add you named anchor manually.

[image]

[image]